# Missing after logout redirect URI in location of response 302

Tags: c#, angular, identityserver4

I have an issue with Identity Server 4, especially with the redirection after logout. I have a JS Client (with Angular, using angular-oauth2-oidc), and so far everything works just fine.
My issue is when I try to logout. My client calls the endession endpoint, with the classic URL, actually containing the post_logout_redirect_uri parameter.

```
https://localhost:5000/connect/endsession?id_token_hint=.....
&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200
```

IdentityServer4 returns a 302 response, with Location header : 'http://localhost:5000/Identity/Account/Logout'. The problem here is that the redirect_uri disappeared somehow in the process... The consequence is, the Logout page does not have a URI to redirect, so it stays in the Logout page...

My client is configured as this :

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "Angular.Client",
    ClientName = "Angular Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    RequireConsent = false,

    // where to redirect to after login
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:4200" },

    // where to redirect to after logout
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:4200" },
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        JwtClaimTypes.GivenName
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:4200" }
},
```

Any help is more than welcome. thanks!

Comment: Does your client configuration have the redirect url?

Comment: @HubertJarema Yes it does, I updated the post with the client configuration

Comment: AllowOfflineAccess should be false for Implicit Grant Type. You shouldn't use use refresh_tokens with JS applications.

Comment: Of course, you're right. Just the result of a bad copy/paste ^^

Comment: Do this: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/logging.html and the logs will tell you what's wrong.